# How to expand a plot graph(MatLab)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a given dataset of x,y values and it gives me the following plot[image].I want to expand my graph in a linear form approximately so the max value of y(in this case 404) to reach the 50% of it and to find the x value for that 50% value(which will be 202) like this one[image].My following code in Matlab is this one:

```
Array=csvread("tek00008.csv");
col1=Array(:,1);
col2=Array(:,2);
plot(col1,col2);
grid on;
hold on;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use the [fit()](https://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html?searchHighlight=fit&s_tid=srchtitle_fit_1#bto2vuv-1-fitType) function.

```
Array=csvread("tek00008.csv");
col1=Array(:,1);
col2=Array(:,2);
plot(col1,col2);
fittedData=fit(col1,col2,'weibull') 
grid on
hold on
plot(fittedData)
```

note that i choose fittype Weibull but it can be different, play around with it a bit. [Here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html#btbcvnl) is the list of all fittype you can choose from (you can evenc reate your own).

Answer (score 0):

**1.- find max coordinates**

```
[ymax,nmax]=max(col2)
xmax=col1(nmax)
```

`nmax` is the index that defines `[xmax ymax]` where the peak takes place.

Assumed just 1 peak as shown in question.

be aware that if the signal is noisy there may be a few samples around the actual sought value that may show up as the max value, masking the peak.

**3.- Calculate zoom window boundaries**

```
x1=.5*xmax;
x2=1.5*xmax;
y1=.5*ymax;
y2=1.1*ymax;
```

These values define what seems to be the 50% mentioned in the question.

Change accordingly with a different zoom window is needed.

**3.- Zoom in with axis**

```
axis([x1 x2 y1 y2])
```

if you show some more detail about your code further assistance may be possible.